# How to handle variable lengths of cell string arrays as an input argument to a function

Tags: matlab, plot, cell-array

I have a function that can plot multiple series on a plot, given a list of table headers wanted as series. I am unsure of how to account for a variable input in the one argument spot, where it accepts either a string, or cell array of strings, depending on how the series should be specifically broken down. For example, calling it as such

```
table2multiseries(myTable, 'Xvals', 'Yvals', 'name');
```

would plot x vs y where each series is for a different name, i.e. "John", "Rob", etc.

Or it can be called with a cell array for the series names, as follows:

```
table2multiseries(myTable, 'Xvals', 'Yvals', {'name', 'trial'});
```

This would plot x vs y where each series is for a different name and trial number, i.e. "John - 1", "John - 2", "Rob - 1", "Rob - 2", etc.

This is the code, where there is an `if` statement that accounts currently for `sName` being either 1, 2, or 3 strings. This is a hack job, no doubt, as it repeats itself about 3 times. I'm wondering how to have it simplified to handle any length of series name criteria inputs. Any ideas?

```
function figHandle = table2multiseries(tb, xName, yName, sName)

    figHandle = figure;
    hold on;

    sList = unique(tb{:, sName}, 'rows');

    if ischar(sName)

        for k = 1:length(sList)
            iRows = tb{:, sName}==sList(k,1);
            leg{sList==s} = [sName ' ' num2str(s)];

            tbtemp = tb(iRows, :);
            tbtemp = sortrows(tbtemp, xName);
            plot(tbtemp{:, xName}, tbtemp{:, yName}, '-o')
        end

    elseif iscellstr(sName) && length(sName)==2

        for k = 1:length(sList)
           iRows = tb{:, sName{1}}==sList(k,1) & tb{:, sName{2}}==sList(k,2)
           leg{k,1} = [sName{1} ' ' num2str(sList(k,1)) ' - ' sName{2} ' ' num2str(sList(k,2)) ];

           tbtemp = tb(iRows ,:);
           tbtemp = sortrows(tbtemp, xName);
           plot(tbtemp{:, xName}, tbtemp{:, yName}, '-o')
        end

    elseif iscellstr(sName) && length(sName)==3

        for k = 1:length(sList)
           iRows = tb{:, sName{1}}==sList(k,1) & tb{:, sName{2}}==sList(k,2) & tb{:, sName{3}}==sList(k,3);
           leg{k,1} = [sName{1} ' ' num2str(sList(k,1)) ' - ' sName{2} ' ' num2str(sList(k,2)) ' - ' sName{3} ' ' num2str(sList(k,3)) ];    

           tbtemp = tb(iRows, :);
           tbtemp = sortrows(tbtemp, xName);
           plot(tbtemp{:, xName}, tbtemp{:, yName}, '-o')   
        end

    end

    title(tb.Properties.Description)
    legend(leg);

end
```

Comment: You can try to use nested for loops. This may be not as efficient as possible, but I think this will not be a problem in this case.